# How to mentally rationalize apt-get install "unable to find package error" and outline a troubleshoot approach

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I've been programming for about 6 months but have just started moving into Operating Systems and the internals of Linux/Ubuntu and how OS's work in general. For my job, I'm tasked to do a lot of configuration setups with packages Linux, nginx,rails, etc and every once in a while I run into an error like the one I am currently experiencing.

```
sudo apt-get install cvsnt

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package cvsnt
```

These errors frustrate me because I don't have a formulated attack plan to troubleshoot it. I'm taking EdX's introduction to Linux and that has been helpful, but the internals of Linux is still a mystery me and when something like this pops up its very difficult for me to figure out what to do. Most of the time I hope that stackoverflow has an answer for the specific problem I'm having.

So how would I attack this problem? There is no error that is helpful other than that the package has not been found. Do I check the CVSNT docs first? Is there something wrong with Ubuntu Linux? Is there something wrong with dpkg? Is there a file to check for stuff? Is it a path problem? Where do you start. I'd like to be able to navigate through these problems effectively because they won't be going away anytime soon as long as I'm assigned to configure things. Thanks.

Comment: This isn't really a programming question -- perhaps it belongs on Superuser?

Comment: That said -- the place to start is the Ubuntu package database for the specific version of Ubuntu you're looking at. http://packages.ubuntu.com/ is a good resource to start with; once you've determined whether it is or isn't available (and, if it is available, which repository it's in, and whether that repository is configured as a source on your machine), then there's room to debug further.

Comment: ...controlling which repositories are and aren't configured as sources is within the configuration for apt-get, so you might consider reading its docs, too.

Comment: I would start troubleshooting from visiting the product's home page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read and understand how Aptitude or apt works. In a nutshell you need to tell it where the CVSNT repository is in sources.list otherwise it will not know.

First make sure the "Universe" is enabled in you etc/apt/sources.list as below where `<YourRelease>` would or could be lucid or trusty if its 14.04. You did not mention which version of Ubuntu you're on. You want this line enabled or if it is not there add it

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ <YourRelease> main universe
```

Then do

```
sudo apt-get update
```

to reread the sources.list then follow that with

```
sudo apt-get install cvsnt
```

See what you get. This should install the correct version of CVSNT and any dependencies required. You will need python running for CVSNT to work.

Good luck and let us know.

Comment: Thanks apesa. It actually turned out that the problem was in the sources.list file.